# How to fill big main content DIV w/different react components depending on menu item chosen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, state, innerhtml

I have the very typical menu/content page. Let's pretend it's about music / movies / tv shows.

Page would look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
Main menu buttons:  Music      Movies     Shows
-------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------
|                                               |
|         BIG EMPTY DIV CALLED "theCONTENT"     |
|                                               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

And then in a -separate- component file I have my MusicStuff component:

(PSEUDOCODE OBVIOUSLY)

```
 // MOVIE STUFF COMPONENT    
import react
import component
import the css stuff too

class MovieStuff extends component
    render(){
       return{
            <image> movie poster <>
            <ol>
               < li className = "all kind of css" >   Actor 1.  <>
               same for actor 2
               etc
               etc
            </ol>
       }

export default MovieStuff
```

When the user clicks "Movies" I would like to dump the MovieStuff component into the "theContent" div.

Naturally, button "TVShows" dumps the TVShowStuff component into theContent, etc.

I've read tons about onclick, states, dangerouslyRenderInnerHTML, hooks, but they always over-complicate the answer.

Or they load the Movie content from the same react file as the main page. My components are in separate component files, for encapsulation reasons.

What I can never quite understand is what steps happen, in which file, to spew the component RadioStuff or TVStuff into theContent when the user clicks its menu item.

I would be very grateful for anyone turning on the lights.

Thanks, and may all your future code at the office always work on the first try.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment is confusing me. You say onclick and hooks are complicating this, but that's like the go to way to implement 95% of stateful logic and user interaction in your application lol.

There are a couple ways to do this.

The absolute simplest, which may be good since you're a beginner. You have your parent component:

```
  const Example = () => {
    const [section, setSection] = useState('music');

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setSection('movies')}>Movies</button>
          {/* etc... */}
        </div>
        <div>
          {section == 'music' && <Music />}
          {section == 'shows' && <Shows />}
          {section == 'movies' && <Movies />}
        </div>
      </div>
     );
  }
```

You import the music, shows, and movies components from their files into that parent content file. And then add in the header, with the 'movies' and 'music' and 'shows' buttons or whatever, with like `onClick={() => setSection('movies')}`. Same for the others.

Now you're conditionally rendering those sections within the page and can work on them as seperate components in their own files.

The other, and perhaps better way to do this is to implement routing. If the user clicks on 'movies, navigate to `example.com/movies` and then here you can use routing to render these sections conditionally. But sometimes you don't want state to persist on reload or you don't want each section to change the path you're on. Regardless, that's a little more advanced, so once you understand this, look up react-router v6 and try that out.

Comment: Sorry, I do apologize.

What I meant is that, yes, some googled solutions mentioned onclicks and hooks but they assumed the content I wanted to dump was in the same file App.js. My situation is different, the components are in different folders under ./components. Also, some answers included everything and the kitchen sink so I wasn't sure what was needed and what was not. Thanks, will try your solution.